Laravel 11 OpenAdmin Gives Error Method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::isDoctrineAvailable does not exist while creating controller
I created a new project in laravel 11 and first I receive error when installing OpenAdmin. It gives error on doctrine/dbal version. Then I watched a youtube video and they first delete the composer.lock file and then install OpenAdmin. I do the same and it got installed. but now I'm trying to create a controller using command as well as helper scaffold but it gives an error.

php artisan admin:controller \App\Models\User
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::isDoctrineAvailable does
not exist.
at
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php:112
public function __call($method, $parameters) {
if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method    )); }
i   Bad Method Call: Did you mean
Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::availableAt() ?
1
vendor\open-admin-org\open-admin\src\Console\ResourceGenerator.php:216
Illuminate\Database\Connection::__call("isDoctrineAvailable", [])
2
vendor\open-admin-org\open-admin\src\Console\ResourceGenerator.php:186
OpenAdmin\Admin\Console\ResourceGenerator::getTableColumns()

Image of the error is attached as well
I have checked all the things it create model, migration, menuItem and everything else but It is not creating controller. and I don't want to create controller manually.

The isDoctrineAvailable method got removed in Laravel 11. So either you have the wrong version of Doctrine, or the wrong Laravel version for this Open Admin version

To use OpenAdmin in Laravel 11, you have to replace one file of that package: src/Console/ResourceGenerator.php
You can find it from OpenAdmin official github repo, but not in Main Branch, but check the Develop branch.
Fix ResourceGenerator for laravel 11

Just replace the https://github.com/open-admin-org/open-admin/blob/develop/src/Console/ResourceGenerator.php file with your OpenAdmin main openadmin package file, then the resource generator will work smoothly.
